# ImageMagick/PHP Resizing Issue: Image Wont Resize, but ImageMagick is installed

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am having an odd issue with ImageMagick.

In the same script, I have the following code:

```
 $ct = system("convert -version");
 echo $ct;
```

And that displays the following response:

```
 Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2012-04-26 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC Features: OpenMP
```

However, when I attempt to do this:

```
 $ct2 = system("convert -resize 800x600 test-image.jpg test-image2.jpg", $retval);
 echo $retval;
```

It returns 1, but the image does not get resized.  Shouldn't a second image be created, resized, under the file name "test-image2.jpg"?  I checked the directory permissions, and they're set to 0777, so that shouldn't be the issue.  Any idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Run the command yourself as the same user to debug: `sudo -u www-data convert -resize 800x600 test-image.jpg test-image2.jpg`

Comment: I just tried to execute the sudo command in SSH, and it says that the sudo command is not found.

Answer (score 1):

A return code of `1` is usually considered an error. `0` means "no error occurred".

I think it is because you have your arguments in the wrong order. ImageMagick wants an input file, a bunch of operations and then an output file. Try to switch order on the arguments:

```
convert test-image.jpg -resize 800x600 test-image2.jpg
```

---

A good idea is to check out the [IMagick](http://php.net/IMagick) extension for PHP. It gives you an object-oriented interface to most of the ImageMagick functions.

Comment: ^ Just attempted that in looking at another script example, and still no luck.  $retval still displays a 1 - which I didn't realize was an error.

Comment: I would love nothing more than to install iMagick - but unfortunately, I'm working on a web host here, and I'm not sure how to install it.  I'm not very well-versed with Terminal, and am not even sure IF I can install it on my host.  And even if I can, not sure where or how.

Comment: @JohnHubler Your host doesn't give you shell access but they allow `system` functions to be executed? If you want to know why a shell-command is failing I suggest going to the source. Debugging with 0 or 1 return values isn't fun.

Comment: It's 1&1 Hosting (www.1and1.com).  I "believe" they offer shell access - but I have no idea how to use it or where to "access" it at

Comment: Okay - I redact my previous statement.  I "CAN" connect to my host via SSH/terminal.  How can I install iMagick from there?

Comment: I have no idea how you install extensions if you are not root. Shared hosting usually means you are locked down to what the hosting provider have installed already. I usually avoid shared hosting for that reason (a VPS is not much more expensive and you get total control).

Comment: I do not use Imagick as the documentation is useless, the options change from one version to the next and there are very few examples and documentation. Saying that I am currently creating examples of all the imagick functions with more examples for my website which should be uploaded later this week.

Comment: Bonzo, I agree with you on the wortless documentation, but I find the extension more useful than GD (which is really resource hungry) or the clunky commandline interface.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to display the error:

```
$array = array(); 
echo "<pre>"; 
exec("convert test-image.jpg -resize 800x600 test-image2.jpg 2>&1", $array);  
echo "<br>".print_r($array)."<br>";  
echo "</pre>";
```

Also I use exec not system, as said above the filename should come straight after convert and I would not use - but _ instead.

System outputs to the screen and exec does not so in your first code you should have been able to use this:

```
system("convert -version");
```

Try this and see what the path to IM is and try changing convert to the path which will probably be something like /usr/local/bin/convert

```
echo "<pre>";
system("type convert"); 
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: That script produces the following:

Array (
    [0] => 
    [1] => libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable
)

Comment: I have never seen that error before! Looking on the IM forum it mentions it in relation to the way IM was installed. A note added to my answer.

Comment: @JohnHubler Once you had the error the top Google result had the answer http://drupal.org/node/1493574#comment-6064852